# How to draw bars of a chart for a chart to full height?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to make the bar with the maximum value take up the entire height of the chart field. How can I do it?

For example, as if in the picture the height of the chart field was up to the green line

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the option [`yAxes.ticks.max`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration), its value should correspond to highest value of the `data` array.

In case the `data` array is defined outside of the chart configuration, you could  use the [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) function as follows:

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    max: Math.max(...data)
  }
}]
```

Please take a look at below sample and see how it works (code is derived from the [Chart.js Bar documentation page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html)).

```js
const data = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40];
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First Dataset",
      data: data,
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)"],
      borderColor: ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)", "rgb(153, 102, 255)", "rgb(201, 203, 207)"],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: Math.max(...data),
          maxTicksLimit: 3
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```